# I'm typically the center attraction of a celebration

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Beauty I can bring, as I make a sound like thunder,
> Over the air I sing, as I am torn asunder.
>
> Of the many wondrous things I can do,
> My favorite is bring light to your view.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess it's

> Fireworks

Beauty I can bring, as I make a sound like thunder,

> Fireworks go boom

Over the air I sing, as I am torn asunder.

> Fireworks do this whistling sound and then blow to their pieces

Of the many wondrous things I can do,
My favorite is bring light to your view.

> aaaand they are bright

And of course, the title

> Fireworks do this, they're awesome

Comment: Would you care to expand your answer?

Comment: there you go then.

Comment: There's one more clue. Are you able to find it? I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: does screeching and singing make the same impact to one's ears? :-)

Comment: I think I wanted whistling

Comment: There's another clue besides the title. I'd look up and down.

Comment: Blake found it first

Answer (score 10):

It is

> FIREWORKS!

Beauty I can bring, as I make a sound like thunder,

> With a flash and a crack, the fireworks explode in the sky

Over the air I sing, as I am torn asunder.

> Screeching as the entire firework falls apart before reaching its peak

Of the many wondrous things I can do, My favorite is bring light to your view.

> From the bright burst of vibrant energy in the sky to the small sparkles of a sparkler, fireworks play with light a great amount.

And the secret hint:

> **B**eauty I can bring, as I make a sound like thunder,
> **O**ver the air I sing, as I am torn asunder.
> **O**f the many wondrous things I can do,
> **M**y favorite is bring light to your view.
>   Joe-You-Know loves his Acrostics ;)

Comment: That I do, that I do. Of Course, since George got it first, I'll give him the accepted answer, but I'm glad at least someone found that secret clue.

Comment: The secret hint was the center attraction of this puzzle! :)

Comment: Oh...so the rule here is to vote the first correct answer if it is missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is either:

> The Budweiser Blimp shooting off fireworks

Or

> A drone shooting missiles into a terrorist party...

Comment: lol that second guess!